# Fastest search for more then 300k data array using key=>value in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

**Simple example array:**

```
$arr = [
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'cat 1'],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'cat 2'],
    ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'cat 1']
];
```

**First Solution**

```
public static function searchForCat($array, $k,$value) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        if (trim(strtolower($val[$k])) === trim(strtolower($value))) {
            return $val;
        }
    }
    return null;
 }
```

**2nd Solution**

```
$categoryKey = array_filter($dataArray, function ($cat, $k) use ($value, $key) {
    return
    trim(strtolower($cat[$key])) == trim(strtolower($value));
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

**3rd solution**

```
$key = array_search($product[$staticAttr['Category Name']], array_column($categories, 'name'));
if($key)
$category = $categories[$key];
```

**4th solution**

```
public static function search_array_kv( $array, $key, $value )
{
   
    $results = array();

    if ( !is_array( $array ) ) return;
    foreach ( $array as $array_value )
    {
        if ( !is_array( $array_value ) ) continue;
        foreach ( $array_value as $subarray )
        {
            if ( !isset( $subarray[ $key ] ) ) continue;
            if ( trim(strtolower($subarray[ $key ])) == trim(strtolower($value ))) $results[] = $subarray;
        }
    }
 
    return current($results);
}
```

I have more then 300k categories where I am migrating 1000k products and each product calling the above search three to four time for category, subcategory and brand name. Which one of the above solution will be more efficient? Any fast solution will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Did you benchmark any of those?

Comment: @MarkusZeller tried all of the above first and 3rd are quite better

Comment: You maybe should use a database and a basic select query.

Comment: @Syscall cannot create three-four db connection for single product.

Comment: @mickmackusa ok will add it lowercase from db. please look into other part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I am not convinced the performing these iterative checks in php is the ideal technique.
2. If you need to trim and convert to lowercase everytime, then I'd say your data wasn't store with searching in mind.
3. `array_filter()` will not be the best performer.  It will continue searching after it finds a satisfactory row.
4. `array_search()` relying on `array_column()` also mean iterating the whole data set then searching the returned column.  This is likely to perform badly.  `$key` might be `false` or `0`, so the loose check is flawed design.
5. You lost me on the 4th snippet, I can't say that I'm comparing apples to apples there.
6. A `foreach()` with an early return will very likely perform best.
7. You should declared `$value = trim(strtolower($value));` before looping because it never changes in the loop and these repeated calls are a waste of resources.
8. Php does very well with checking keys.  If you are somehow able to leverage key checks by modifying how your data is stored, performance may improve (at a cost of memory).
9. Personally, I'd probably try to use a database for this task with appropriate indexes.